# How to print a method (removeTopClass) from another class into a loop?

Tags: java, loops, stack

I'm working through this assignment at the moment, which I've done most of the work for at this point.

```
public String getRankAsString() {
String[] ranks = "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
"7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A" 
return ranks[rank];
}
```

and suit

```
public String getSuitAsString() {
String[] suits = { "Clubs", "Diamonds", 
"Hearts", "Spades" };
    return suits[suit];
}
```

I am supposed to create 2 classes within the lab package, one called LabApp (where the testing would happen) and DiscardPile, a subclass of Stack and **would contain a method "discardTopCard",  method called removeTopCards which accepts a reference to a Card object called theCard. This method will allow the user to request that all cards up to and including theCard be removed from the discard pile and returned in an array, thus the return-type of the method is Card[]. This is what I have for removeTopCard atm.**

```
public Card[] removeTopCard(Card otherCard) throws StackEmptyException {
        Card[] theCard = new Card[size()];
        int i = 0;
        boolean check = false;

        if(isEmpty()){ //in the case that there's nothing there
          throw new StackEmptyException("Stack is Empty");
        }
        while(!isEmpty()){ //If it's not empty, pop the top card (unlimited loop that'll need to be broken by a break;)

          Card top = (Card) pop(); //Casts Card to pop, which should remove it
          theCard[i] = top; //removed and returned in an array
          i++; 
          if(top.equals(otherCard)){ //checks if the card's rank and suit are the same and stops the loop if true
            check = true;
            break; //it ends the loop if they're equivalent, all of those cards were set to top
          }
        }
        if(!check){ //if it can't find anything
          throw new StackEmptyException("Card not found");
        }
        Card[] topCards = new Card[i];

        for(int j = 0;j < i; j++){

          topCards[j] = theCard[j]; //set the discarded value array to theCard
        }
        return topCards; //should return the popped numbers
      }
```

I **THINK** this could work just fine.

In LabApp, the testing method, I currently have the discardPile.push method working just fine

```
        discardPile.push(new Card(41));

        for(int i = 0; i < discardPile.getSize(); i++) {
            Card var = discardPile.pop(); //pops the cards that are above
                System.out.println(var.getRankAsString() + " of " + var.getSuitAsString());
        }

        }
        catch (StackEmptyException SEE) {
            System.out.println("StackEmptyException: " + SEE.getMessage());
        }
        catch (StackFullException SFE) {
            System.out.println("StackFullException: " + SFE.getMessage());
       }
}
}
```

It's printing the desired output, no problem

I am also supposed to write a **call to the removeTopCards method** and test the method by passing a reference to a card whose integer value is 20.

I know I write it like this

```
discardPile.removeTopCard(new Card(20));
```

but I don't know how I'd go about printing it through a for loop.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: WHat you want to print? Make it clear please. Is it the card, that is being poped?

Comment: @MD.NASHIDKAMAL This method will allow the user to request that all cards up to and including the current card (theCard) be removed from the discard pile and returned in an array and leaving the rest there. It is a method within the DiscardPile class.

Comment: Yes. But I'm still  confused whats problem here. Using a for loop, what you want to print?

Comment: `Card[] cardArr = discardPile.removeTopCard(new Card(20)); for(Card c : cardArr) {System.out.println(c);}`

Comment: @MD.NASHIDKAMAL I don't know how to print the removeTopClass into the testing class, which is LabApp.

Comment: okay .. got it. You want to Use `removeTopCard()` from LabApp, right?

Comment: @MD.NASHIDKAMAL Yeah, exactly that.

Comment: @GBlodgett I will try that in a moment. Does my removeTopCard function look good to you?

Comment: did you used `Card[] cardArr` as Global Array ?

Comment: As you mentioned in your question, it working preety good.

Comment: @MD.NASHIDKAMAL GBlodgett's code works perfectly. I need to print them backward.

Comment: @GBlodgett Your code works but there's no space in between suit and rank. How can I achieve that?

Comment: @LostSoul You would have to override the `toString()` method to put a space in between